# Vertically and Horizontally Align Bootstrap Row on Page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to fronted HTML/CSS and am using Bootstrap to get my sites pages up and looking good and being responsive. However I have a page with an input search box and want it to be centered on the page. This is what my HTML looks like:

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* for search bar */

.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon {
  background: white !important;
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control {
  border-right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div id="imaginary_container">
        <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" autofocus>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <button type="submit">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am hoping to do is to center the search box on the page, similar to Google's homepage. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Your code is already working, why do you think is not working? if you mean on smaller windows just add col-md-6 and col-xs-6 to your div and then respectively col-md-offset-3 and col-xs-offset-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to use a centring concept here. I have used the `transform` method.

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Snippet here:

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* for search bar */

.stylish-input-group .input-group-addon {
  background: white !important;
}
.stylish-input-group .form-control {
  border-right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.stylish-input-group button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div id="imaginary_container">
        <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" autofocus>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <button type="submit">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup this did the trick, but it seemed to stretch my page out (I could scroll vertically on my 1080p monitor), so I changed position form absolute to fixed. Again I am a noob, should fixed position be something I stay away from?

Comment: @ng150716 Yea, `position: absolute` does it for you. So do one thing. Add another `mega-container` on top of container and add the styles. That should keep everything intact.

Comment: Your absolute right,I applied the transform to another class nested in `container`, applying the style to container solves everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Centered form in Twitter Bootstrap:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .center {
        vertical-align: center;
    }
</style

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 center">
        <form>
            <input type="text">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Vertical centering... See my answer. `:)`

Comment: Not sure... Let the OP say. I have removed your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use flex layout, add a class to your div:

```css
.search-bar {
  min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh; /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row search-bar">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
          <div id="imaginary_container">
            <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" autofocus>
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="submit">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And then use `display:flex` and `align-items:center` for your css.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the flexbox centering for vertical align

```
#imaginary_container{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
height: 100vh;
```

}

For horizontal centering, you can use the Bootstrap class .text-center
for example:

```
<div class="input-group text-center stylish-input-group" style="
text-align: center;"></div>
```